# .hasClass on.click not registering for a function call until a second .click..ajax async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, promise

Some checkbox buttons (using bootstrap) trigger an ajax get call on.click, and the activeness of the checked buttons serves a filtering mechanism.

Right now, why is the filtering only working correctly on.click of a second click event (if btn1 is clicked, the ajax runs, with /.one.two.three... and only when btn2 is subsequently clicked does it register as /.two.three.. and only when btn3 is subsequently clicked does it registers as /.three..? http://jsfiddle.net/ENJH9/2/

Alternatively, if the refreshData() call is preceded by removing the class on.click, the data is served correctly, but the view does not reflect the removeClass!? http://jsfiddle.net/ENJH9/3/

All the buttons start with an active class (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="theBtns">
  <label class="btn btn1 active">
    <input type="checkbox">one
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn2 active">
    <input type="checkbox">two
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn3 active">
    <input type="checkbox">three
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn4 active">
    <input type="checkbox">four
  </label>
</div>
```

Here's the .get Call that follows the .click event of each button:

```
function refreshData() {

    console.log('started refreshData()')

    URL = '';

    var filtering = function() {

        if($(".btn1").hasClass("active")) { URL += ".one"; }
        if($(".btn2").hasClass("active")) { URL += ".two"; }
        ...

    console.log('done filtering: ' + URL);

        return URL;
    };

    $.when( filtering() ).done(function() {

    console.log('now data refresh with %s filtering', URL)

    $.ajax({
      url:"http://localhost:4200/api/v1/data" + URL,
      method:'get',
      success: foundAllSuccess,
      error: foundError

    })

    });

}
```

And here's the click event with the removeClass commented out (the buttons still remained visually active and the class still remained in the inspector, but the server accurately filters with this setup):

```
$( ".btn1" ).click(function() {
  // if($(".btn1").hasClass("active")) {$(".btn1").removeClass("active"); console.log('hide btn1 data');}
  // else {$(".btn1").addClass("active"); console.log('btn1 data active');}
  refreshData();
}); // .btn1.click
```

Comment: What do you think the point of that `$.when(filtering()).done` is? Calling `.when` on a URL is rather pointless, why can't you just call it without the `.when` ?

Comment: he has an ellipse in the filtering(), he does not have all the implementation of filtering included in his question because it is unnecessary obviously. so you can assume it is a long running function is why is using .when

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the .when was one thought as to how to get the hasClass to precede the ajax call.. the URL is then appended to the url as just now edited.. any other suggestions for getting the URL to accurately reflect the active states of the btns?

Comment: Can you make an isolated fiddle?

Comment: @BrianOgden thanks for the comment.. the post has been updated to reflect where the URL var is utilized.. Any suggestions for getting the active states of the btns to be accurately represented by the URL var?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes, though have to step away for a bit.. Will fiddle when I get back, and let you know.. Many thanks

Comment: I don't get `active`. Does the `active` class of the labels relate to the checked state of the checkboxes? Where is the code that adds/removes `active`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yeh, active relates to the checked state of the checkboxes..http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks again for looking at this.. Here are the fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/ENJH9/2/ (first scenario) and http://jsfiddle.net/ENJH9/3/ (second scenario)

Comment: Ah right, so classname `active` is bootstrap-managed?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes, exactly

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't need to toggle `active` yourself. By allowing bootstrap to toggle and doing the same in your code, the nett effect is no change of state ... however, that's not the only source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the main reason you are having a problem is that bootstrap and jQuery don't sit too comfortably together - at least not in this case. jQuery's click event is dispatched so early, it happens before bootstrap has toggled 'active'. Therefore `refreshData()` operates on the button state before the click, not after the click. This can be overcome with a `timeout()` to delay execution of `refreshData()` until after bootstrap has done its thing.

Secondly, you don't need to toggle `active` as bootstrap looks after that aspect.

Thirdly, the code can be written more efficiently by better leveraging jQuery.

```
function refreshData(e) {
    var URL = $(e.target).closest(".btn-group").find("label").map(function (i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            return ['.one', '.two', '.three', '.four'][i];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }).get().join(''); //.map() returns an array, .join() concatenates the strings in the array into a single string.

    alert('now ajax call with filtering :' + URL);
}

$("#theBtns .btn").on('click', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshData(e);
    }, 0);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ENJH9/4/)**

Note that even a delay of zero is enough for our purpose, as code executed from a `setTimeout` will run in a separate event thread at the earliest opportunity after the current thread has run to completion.

There may be a more "bootstrapy" way to achieve the same end but I'm not about to wade through tons of bootstrap documentation to find out.